# What does this mean? where isnull(column,' ') <= ' '

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone please help me understand this:

```sql
where isnull(column,' ') <= ' '
```

In SQL this is the `where` clause, it looks like it is comparing a space less than or equal to a space? What does that mean? Can someone shed some light.

Comment: What is the data type of `column`?  I should also note that there are, no doubt, clearer ways to write the logic.

Comment: It's checking the value is "less than" a single white space. *Why* is a very different question (and we can't anserr that question). It's also not the most performant way of doing so.

Comment: the data type if nvarchar,

Comment: I was told this was used to compare against the table to only bring in the most recent values that are not available. but i just dont get it blows my mind

Comment: In a standalone context such as this that explanation makes no sense at all.  The only thing I can see this doing is checking if the value of  `column` is NULL, empty string or single whitespace.  Can you post the rest of the query and some sample data?

Comment: Agreed that explanation doesn't make any sense. This is *almost* a feasible way to check for any values that start with a control character, but doing <= on a string doesn't actually use the character value. See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c583d/3/0

Answer (score 2):

So I will admit I can't see any benefit or purpose to this statement - however it's very easy to test and see the result.

You might expect, at a glance, it would select rows where the column is either null or, when compared alphabetically, "less" than a space, which is basically all non-printable *ascii* characters.

It doesn't even do that since comparisons of character codes less than 32 (an ascii space) do not (unsurprisingly) work.

With a bit of test data

```
create table t (ch nvarchar(2), id int)

insert into t select 'A'              ,1
insert into t select ' '              ,2
insert into t select '3'              ,3
insert into t select ''               ,4
insert into t select null             ,5
insert into t select Char(13)         ,6
insert into t select Char(15)         ,7
insert into t select Char(31)+Char(30),8
```

You might expect rows `2,5,6,7,8` are "less than or equal to" a space.

```
select * 
from t
where IsNull(ch,' ') <= ' '
```

However this returns `2,4,5` - so an empty string is considered less than a space, but the `ascii` values less than 32 are not.

If you actually wanted to find all *ascii* values less than or equal to a space (32) you'd have to use the `ascii` function which gives exactly the expected results

```
select *
from t
where IsNull(ascii(ch),32)<=32
```

which returns `2,4,5,6,7,8` - it excludes the A and 3 which are obviously "higher" than a space but includes the blank value, since that evaluates to `null` and thus 32.

As to what it *actually* accomplishes - only proper sample data and the complete context could answer.

Comment: I guess theoretically the result depends on the selected collation, but I don't imagine the relative sort order of space varies much.